# Calico node status returns Calico process is not running

Tags: kubernetes, calico

I've problems getting with the BGP Peers of my Kubernetes clusters. My Cluster is built with 3 master nodes and 2 worker nodes on premise running on Unbuntu 18.04. The etcd is external configurered but running on 2 Master Nodes. 
Initialy initialized with the pod cidr 172.16.0.0/16, but recently changed to 192.168.220.0/24. 
I've installed Calico the latest version.
Every seems to be working OK when I configured a replicaset of 1 of each services. When I run multible pods I have connection problems with my configured services sometimes, sometimes not.

After some reasearch I discovered the problem could be a misconfiguration of Calico. When I run calicoctl node status I see this.

[image]

On the calico side I discovered it has something to do with BGP peering but I can't figure out what went wrong. The nodes had IP connectivity. A telnet session to port TCP 179 is also succesfull. What can I check next? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: calico is diesgned to work with --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16 by default. Have you tried to test  if you have same problems with default CIDR?

Comment: Yes, I've already did. That worked too. Even I tested it with a much more simple cluster with the same IP range 192.168.220.0/24 -> this worked too. So The problem deals with Calico configurered in our big cluster. But I can't find out what is wrong.